# google translate api v2 response with code 403 and reason 'dailyLimitExceeded'

Tags: google-translate

I have billing account 'Z' connected with project 'X' and google translate api enabled for this project.

Trying to perform GET request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key={my_key}&q=hello&source=en&target=ru
```

got output:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded",
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded"
      }
    ]
  }
```

tried to generate another api key, all in vein, api key has no restrictions.

Comment: Issue might be from google, report your issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70990743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that should have been Fixed as of now, please try again to see if you're still seeing this issue and re-open the Issue [#70990743](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70990743) if necessary.